# using jquery how do i get textbox value in table cell on button click in repeater control

Tags: jquery, textbox, repeater, cell

I have a repeater control and in each cell there is some text, bid button, and a textbox for bid amount.  Im trying to get the textbox value (Bid amount) when the user clicks the button in the same cell so I can validate the bid amount.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my html table code:

```
<table id="values" class="values" border="3">
<tr>
<td  align="center"  style="white-space:nowrap">
<span class="MainBgContent_UpperRight_Title" style="height:25px;max-height:25px">Your Bid: $
<asp:TextBox ID="tbBid" CssClass="bids" Style="width: 30px" runat="server" Text=''></asp:TextBox>

</span>                                                
<div style="height:10px;clear:both;"></div>

<div class="offer" style="width:100px;height:30px;line-height:20px;">                                                    
<asp:Button style="width:100px;height:30px;line-height:20px;"  Visible="true"  CssClass="btnSubmitBid"  ID="lbBid" Text="BID" runat="Server" CommandName="makeBid"    ></asp:Button>                                                    
</div>
<div style="height:20px;clear:both;"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can get the id of the button via class name btnSubmitBid, but need to get the textbox value for that specific cell only.

thank you

Comment: Try $(button).closest('td').find('bids').val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the javascript function for the click of the button, you can traverse the DOM tree to find the input.  Since the button is in a div, which is in the cell, you need to get the button's [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) (div)'s parent (cell).  Then find the first [child](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (the span), and that span's child:

```
var bid = $(this).parent().parent().children()[0].children()[0];
```

Or you can use the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function on the cell to look for the input:

```
var bid = $(this).parent().parent().find("input");
```

Or, use the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function, although I'm not sure if there is a big performance difference, and you already know the structure to know how far up you need to look to find the cell:

```
var bid = $(this).closest('td').find("input");
```

This answer assumes there is only on input in the table.  If there is more than one, you should look for the class of `.bids` instead of the element type of `input`.

Comment: This is what I tried and it doesnt seem to show the value of the textbox for the bid anount.$(document).ready(function () {

            $(".btnSubmitBid").click(function () {

                var bid = $(this).parent().parent().children[0].children[0];
                alert(bid.val());

            });
        });

Comment: Thank you Scott.  Got it working using the var bid = $(this).closest('td').find("input");

Comment: It should have been children()[0] (I have since edited).  I forgot the parens.  But I'n glad you got it working.